# Drupal - Devel Themer not showing

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

At first, it was showing me `Class 'simple_html_dom' not found in ...` but I found the solution. Now even though `Theme Developer` module is activated, it doesn't show the radio box to check on the bottom left corner and Drupal doesn't show any error whatsoever, but...
When inspecting the browser's console I found this error :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'themer_info' of undefined`

This is happening in the file `modules/devel_themer/devel_themer.js` on line 43

Has anybody got this module working in Drupal 7 ?

Comment: Do you have jquery update module installed?

Comment: No, but it's searching in the `Drupal.settings` variable, are you sure this is jQuery related ?

Comment: The `thmrStrings` is setted in `devel_themer.module` line 666. It should be available in your javascript. Try to add line: `console.log(Drupal.settings)` to your devel_themer.js and see the output..

Comment: You can also check other issues of that module.. if it's common bug.. https://drupal.org/project/issues/devel_themer?categories=All

Comment: Install this module and try again : [simplehtmldom](https://drupal.org/project/simplehtmldom)

Answer (score 3):

Had this same issue and fixed it.
From the devel_themer drupal page (https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer):

> **NOTE**:
>   Currently, Theme Developer does not work with the latest version of
>   simplehtmldom API. You must use simplehtml API version 7.x-1.12 if you want Theme Developer > to function properly.

Did as it suggested and it works, annoying that it was such a pain to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is related to the JavaScript wrapper of Drupal. As a quick solution you may comment out following strings in the includes/common.inc file:

```
$embed_prefix = "\n<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--\n";
$embed_suffix = "\n//--><!]]>\n";
```

So, it should look like this:

```
//    $embed_prefix = "\n<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--\n";
//    $embed_suffix = "\n//--><!]]>\n";
```

Don't forget to restore the original file contents when you are done. Hope that helps.